# How to pass multiple values in exec command resource in puppet?

Tags: linux, puppet

I want to deploy certs in default keystore using puppet

I have two files root.crt and intermediateca.crt managed by puppet. I will have many alias and cert file in future

Alias could be rootca, intermediateca.This alias and filepath should be passed to exec command.

```
alias=rootca, intermediateca
filecert= "/var/lib/certs/rootca", "/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt"
```

Now I am running an exec command which takes alias and crt file as an argument in exec command resource.

```
    '/var/lib/certs':
      ensure => directory;

    '/var/lib/certs/root.crt':
      source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/sonarqube/${::env}/var/lib/certs/root.crt",
      mode   => '0644',
      notify => Exec['markitrootca'];

    '/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt':
      source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/sonarqube/${::env}/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt",
      mode   => '0644',
      notify => Exec['markitintermediateca'];

  }
  exec {
    'markitrootca':
      path => "/usr/bin",
      command => "keytool -importcert -keystore ${keystore} -alias markitrootca -file /var/lib/certs/root.crt  -storepass ${storepass} -noprompt  2>/dev/null",
      provider => shell,
      refreshonly => true;

    'markitintermediateca':
      path => "/usr/bin",
      command => "keytool -importcert -keystore ${keystore} -alias markitintermediateca  -file /var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt/ -storepass ${storepass} -noprompt 2>/dev/null",
      provider => shell,
      refreshonly => true;
  }
```

The above solution is working fine but I want to write only one exec for multiple alias and filepaths. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

What it sounds like you are asking here is how to iterate over a hash and have each resource in the iteration notify an `exec` resource. Given that, you can use a lambda iterator on the hash. If this is not true, then please clarify the question with terminology and details. First you construct the hash with your keys:

```
$certs = { 'rootca'         => '/var/lib/certs/rootca',
           'intermediateca' => '/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt' }
```

Then you can iterate over the hash with the `each` method.

```
$certs.each |String $cert, String $loc| {
  # code here
}
```

Populating the body of the lambda would look like this for your situation:

```
$certs.each |String $cert, String $loc| {
  file { $loc:
    source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/sonarqube/${::env}${loc}",
    mode   => '0644',
    notify => Exec['install_cert'];
  }
}
```

Note that in your question it looked like you were doing per-resource default attributes, but it is unclear since the rest of the body is missing, so I converted it to a conventional resource.

The entire body of code would look like:

```
$certs = { 'rootca'         => '/var/lib/certs/rootca',
           'intermediateca' => '/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt' }

$certs.each |String $cert, String $loc| {
  file { $loc:
    source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/sonarqube/${::env}${loc}",
    mode   => '0644',
    notify => Exec['install_cert'];
  }
}

exec { 'install_cert':
  path        => "/usr/bin",
  command     => "keytool -importcert -keystore ${keystore} -alias $alias -storepass ${storepass} -noprompt -trustcacerts",
  provider    => linux,
  subscribe   => File['/var/lib/certs/'],
  refreshonly => true;
}
```

Since you did not mention in the question what `keystore` and `storepass` are, I will have to assume you are defining them elsewhere. Also you are subscribing to `File['/var/lib/certs/']` which I also have to assume is somewhere else.

There are other improvements you can make here, including:

- Not specifying the provider in the `exec`.
- Not using the `path` in the `exec` since it is a string and not an array of search paths and instead providing the full path to `keytool`.
- Not subscribing to `File['/var/lib/certs/']` since the `exec` does not care about that directory and the `notify` are providing the necessary functionality.
- Not specifying the path to the certs since they are always in the same location, so you can use a single array instead of a hash.
- `env` looks like a fact and not a global variable, so it should be specified as such.
- Not having a deep `source` for your `file` resources and instead just storing them inside the `env` directory.

Helpful documentation on lambda iterators can be found [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_iteration.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way to do this. you can simple define a `hiera`yaml file with an array of objects/task or just write it directly in.

instead of code such as

```
  # Run Start Script* 
  exec { 'run  script':
    command     => "somecmdhere",
    provider    => shell,
    cwd         => 'dir',
    refreshonly => false,
    logoutput   => true
  }

  exec { 'run installation script':
    command     => "${target_dir}/${start_service_script}",
    provider    => shell,
    cwd         => $target_dir,
    refreshonly => false,
    logoutput   => $cmdlogoutput
  }
```

you can use create resource with arguments TYPE and Objects to create

`create_resources('package', )`

in this case we would use

```
#goes and looks for yaml file with variable exec scripts. This can be done by also defining it in puppet. 

$listofExecCommands = hiera_hash('execScripts::allscripts)





create_resources('exec', $listofExecCommands)
```

Then where ever you define your YAML file you can re-use it with no code changes.
you can use this for RPMS NPM packages its great! ps make sure your yaml is correct*

```
#RPM packages to be installed
execScripts::allscripts:
   'script1':
     command: 'installed'
     provider: 'yum'
     cwd: 'somedir'
   'script2':
     command: 'installed'
     provider: 'yum'
     cwd: 'somedir'
```